# Windows 8 WinJS app CSS not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have a game written in Windows 8 (WinJS).  My aim is to have the game appear in landscape or filled mode, but then for other orientations, just display the app logo in the center of the screen.  Here's what I have so far:

```
    <canvas id="mainCanvas">
    </canvas>
    <img id="imageLogo" src="/images/logo.png" />            
    <div id="adControl" style="width: 728px; height: 90px; visibility:visible; margin-bottom: 0px; z-index: 1"        
        data-win-control="MicrosoftNSJS.Advertising.AdControl"
        data-win-options="{applicationId: 'app-id', adUnitId: 'add-unit-id', isAutoRefreshEnabled: 'true'}">
    </div>
```

The styles are as follows:

```
@media screen and (-ms-view-state: fullscreen-landscape) {
#imageLogo {
    visibility:collapse;
    display:none;
}
#adControl {
    visibility:visible;
    display:normal;
}
#mainCanvas {
    visibility:visible;
}
}

@media screen and (-ms-view-state: snapped) {
#adControl {
    visibility:collapse;
    display:none;
}
#mainCanvas {
    visibility:collapse;
    display:none;
}
#imageLogo {
    clear:both;
    float:none;        
    visibility:visible;
    display:normal;
    margin: 0px 0px;        
}
```

I've only included full screen landscape and snapped because the others are the same.  Here is the only game code that I think is relevant to the sizing:

```
var setupCanvas = function (changed) {
    if (Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value === Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.fullScreenLandscape
        || Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value === Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.filled) {
        canvas.width = window.outerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.outerHeight - 90;
    } else {
        clearInterval(gameLoopId);
    }
}
```

Basically it just resizes the canvas and for other modes suspends the game loop.

What it is actually doing is displaying the logo in landscape, and thus displacing the ad control and, in other modes, it's displaying all three elements but incorrectly sized.

What is wrong with the CSS? (I did try using an ms-grid, but couldn't get that to work at all)

Comment: Your CSS says #imageLogo and your HTML says logoImage.  Names don't match.

Comment: I would start with the above comment your names don't match.

Comment: DOH!  Never spotted that.  However, it doesn't solve the problem.  I still get the add control displaying on the portrait and it's still displaced on the landscape (although oddly it now doesn't actually show on landscape).

Comment: A couple guesses (haven't tested either). (1) Just for kicks, try "display: none" instead of changing visibility. (2) I don't know what triggers your setupCanvas function and if it gets triggered when the view state changes.  Try handling the window.onresize event.

Actually, before either of those, are you sure the CSS is correct in the CSS media rules?  Try removing the conditions (one at a time) and making sure that the CSS does what you expect it to do.  If your changes are CSS, then you shouldn't need to worry about resize events since the media queries will take care for that for you.

Comment: Unbelievably, display:none does work.  I'm already handling window.onresize, but it doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: update the code above to current (correct the names, etc) and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Okay - I've corrected the names.  The state it's currently in is that it hides and shows correctly, but it seems to display at the top of the screen just left of centre (I want it smack in the centre).  Oddly, it seems to behave differently when I rotate the screen (via the emulator) and when I start the app the the relevant view mode.

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same issues as pm_2. Setting display to none works but that's all that works on snapped view. Also when using blend expression, the changes made with wysiwyg interface gets updated at the wrong css code location. When I was resizing for Snapped view, the main css codes were been updated. Not nice..

My CSS Code

```
.homepage section[role=main] {
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-right: 26px;
}
@media screen and (-ms-view-state: snapped) {
.homepage section[role=main] {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.homepage .deadline {
    display:none;
}

.homepage .todos{
   position: fixed;
       height: 225px;
       right: 421px;
       left: 45px;
       top: 135px;
}

  .homepage .chart {
  display: none;
  }
}


@media screen and (-ms-view-state: portrait) {
    .homepage section[role=main] {
    margin-left: 100px;
    }
}

@media screen and (-ms-view-state: fullscreen-portrait) {
    .homepage section[role=main] {
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-right: 100px;
     }
}

.homepage body {
    color: white;
}

 .homepage .chart {
    background-color: #36073c;
    position: absolute;
    height: 495px;
    right: 766px;
    left: 125px;
    top: 150px;
}

.homepage .deadline {
    background-color: #36073c;
    /*border: 4px solid black;*/
    position: absolute;
    height: 495px;
    right: 421px;
    left: 640px;
    top: 150px;
 }

.homepage .deadline:hover {
    border: 3px solid yellow;
}

.homepage .todos {
    background-color: #36073c;
    /*border: 4px solid black;*/
    position: absolute;
    height: 495px;
    right: 86px;
    left: 975px;
    top: 150px;
}

 .homepage .todos:hover {
    border: 3px solid yellow;
 }

 .homepage .box-title {
     height: 8%;
     font-size: 22px;
     font-weight: bolder;
     padding: 5px 10px;
     color: #fff;
 }

 .homepage .box-content {
     height: 87.96%;
 }

.homepage .tabular-data {
    margin: 20px 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

.homepage .tabular-data tr td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```